# Get object value returned from mongo query in same controller

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

how can i get the object returned from a mongodb query and use it in the same controller? currently im unable to get the object attributes out of it. For example my object has a month ,Below is a code sample:

```
budgetsApp.controller('BudgetsCostbreakdownController', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location,$modal,$log, Authentication, Budgets) {

    // Get current budget
    $scope.budget = Budgets.get({ 
                budgetId: $stateParams.budgetId
            });

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'My Budget and Expenses for month of'+$scope.budget.budgetMonth //wont appear in my view .
    };
        //end chart
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use callback for this purpose `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`

```
// Get current budget
Budgets.get({budgetId: $stateParams.budgetId}, function(response) {
    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'My Budget and Expenses for month of'+ response.budgetMonth //wont appear in my view .
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Budgets` object equals [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) defined somewhere in your code you need to "wait" until data arrives from your RESTful backend.

```
// Get current budget
Budgets.get({ 
  budgetId: $stateParams.budgetId
}).$promise.then(function(result){
  $scope.chartObject.options = {
    'title': 'My Budget and Expenses for month of' + result.budgetMonth
  };
});
```